# Not able to build session factory in servlet init method

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

I am trying to use hibernate with servlet. as SessionFactory took lots of time to initialise i decided to build session factory in init method. below is my servlet code.

```
public void init()throws ServletException
{
    factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

}
```

but i gets the error as follows.

```
Sep 10, 2013 4:27:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet cgi as unavailable
Sep 10, 2013 4:27:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /school threw load() exception
java.lang.SecurityException: Restricted class org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet
at  org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.checkAccess(DefaultInstanceManager.java:432)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.checkAccess(DefaultInstanceManager.java:423)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:399)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1043)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5279)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Sep 10, 2013 4:27:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [StaffAttendanceReport] in context with path    [/school] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at com.enext.security.base.BaseServlet.getSessionFactory(BaseServlet.java:45)
at com.enext.edu.school.attendance.servlet.StaffAttendanceReport.service(StaffAttendanceReport.java:56)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.smartware.antisql.AntiSQLFilter.doFilter(AntiSQLFilter.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at Filters.BlockSplChrFliter.doFilter(BlockSplChrFliter.java:46)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

what is meaning of this exception.

```
SEVERE: Servlet /school threw load() exception
java.lang.SecurityException: Restricted class org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet
```

I changed the tomcat and tried the same i got below exception

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

below is my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port:sid</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">uname</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">passwd</property>       
<mapping resource="com/enext/edu/school/attendance/entity/EmployeeMaster.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="com/enext/edu/school/attendance/entity/StudentHolidayMasterBean.hbm.xml"/>    
<mapping resource="com/enext/edu/school/attendance/entity/EmployeeSignin.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

how can i solve the problem ?

Comment: Make sure you have all dom4j releated jars in your class path and lib folder

Comment: when i comments factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); the application works fine. the library is included already.

Answer (score 0):

seems some jar missing..dom4j-1.5.2.jar as u get `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException`

Comment: when i comments factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); the application works fine. the library is included already.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing with `dom4j` jars, Please make sure you have these dependacy

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version><version></version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: when i comments factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); the application works fine. the library is included already.

Comment: sorry didn't get the exact context, do you mean when commenting the sessionfactory, application is working and you are able to perssit, how this is possible without sessionfactory ? between when your application tries to build sessionfactory it looks for the set up required libraries, and your stack trace clearly shows that...http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html this link might help you to understand noclassdeffound exception, please cross check your library(web-inf/lib)